# Should I concatenate/minify already minified JS/CSS? If so, how?

Tags: javascript, css, minify, google-closure-compiler, yui-compressor

Our app has several JS library dependencies which are already minified.  We're considering concatenating them into a single file to reduce the volume of separate threads the browser needs to download them all.

The minifiers I've looked at so far don't handle this well (examined Google Closure Compiler, YUI Compressor).  I don't really need my already minified libraries minified again.  What is the standard practice for this in the JS world?  And do I need to worry about specifying order?

Question is similar for CSS.  These libraries provide pre-minified CSS, which I'd like to concatenate together.

Comment: Why not to concatenate the contents manually? or dynamically by command line apps?

Comment: use a task runner like grunt or gulp (e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat). Of course the order it's important both for js and css file

Comment: @HashemQolami we can do that, but I wondered if there were a safe and proven library already that folks used.  Or whether concatenating minified files was even considered a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Yes it's safe. As long as you concatenate them in the same order that they are linked in the HTML.

Comment: It does however affect sourcemaps if you use them.

Comment: If your application is written in java, WUIC (http://wuic.github.io/) is a project that is able to merge your scripts. It can also analyze your HTML page to collect the script and aggregate them in the correct order without the need to take care of it.

Comment: Things you need to watch out for:  "use strict" at the start of any file.  If the first one has it they all become strict, if it isn't the first one it will be ignored.
You also have to watch out for files that don't terminate with a newline, as semicolon insertion can cause unexpected results.
Moving forward, you need to be careful not to concatenate ES6 modules.

If those aren't a problem, you can use a simple script to concatenate the files, or you can use the Closure Compiler's whitespace only mode.

Answer (score 1):

You typically wouldn't minify code that is already minified. If the provided minified library was minified in a bad way (like packer), it would be better to minify the original library source code using your favorite minifier.

In your case it's better to look at concatenation only.

You can do this using [Gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) or [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat). Both are able to generate sourcemaps.

I have not had any trouble with `use strict` when concatenating multiple libraries to a single file, but it is something to pay attention to. Properly written libraries apply `use strict` only to their library scope, to not affect the global scope / other libraries.

If some silly library applies `use strict` to the global scope, and another silly library is not compatible with strict, Firefox (probably Chrome as well) throw a strict violation error immediately, so this error is easy to spot.